# OpenVPN Tap vs Tun Mode

Tags: network, certificates, vpn

I would like to know practical difference between **TAP and TUN mode when use with OpenVPN**.

When to use TAP and When to use TUN ?

What types of **traffic** will pass with both mode ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

TAP is basically at Ethernet level (layer 2) and acts like a switch where as TUN works at network level (layer 3) and routes packets on the VPN. TAP is bridging whereas TUN is routing.

From the [OpenVPN Wiki](https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/BridgingAndRouting):

> **TAP benefits:**
>
> - behaves like a real network adapter (except it is a virtual network    adapter)
> - can transport any network protocols (IPv4, IPv6, Netalk, IPX, etc,    etc)
> - Works in layer 2, meaning Ethernet frames are passed over the VPN    tunnel
> - Can be used in bridges
>
> **TAP drawbacks:**
>
> - causes much more broadcast overhead on the VPN tunnel
> - adds the overhead of Ethernet headers on all packets transported over    the VPN tunnel
> - scales poorly
>
> **TUN benefits**:
>
> - A lower traffic overhead, transports only traffic which is destined    for the VPN client
> - Transports only layer 3 IP packets
>
> **TUN drawbacks:**
>
> - Broadcast traffic is not normally transported
> - Can only transport IPv4 (OpenVPN 2.3 adds IPv6)
> - Cannot be used in bridges